# html5 number type to accept only positive integers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using an angular app, with an html5 number type input. I am trying to restrict the input to only accepts positive integers and not decimal, floating point numbers.

I tried using some patterns and step=1 min, max values but does not seem to work.

Please suggest.

EDIT:

This is how my form looks like. Sorry for the confusion if I may have cause.

```
<div class="row bottom-spaced-small">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Number*
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input name="txtNumber" ng-disabled="somevalue" min="1" step="1" type="number" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="someNumber" class="form-control color-black" />
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-left: 30px" ng-if="someForm.$submitted && !someForm.txtNumber.$valid">
            <span style="color: red">Number is mandatory and must be a non 0 positive number.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where can we find your code ?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://sscce.org)? Simply setting min=1 [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rhxmqzyq/).

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: @phihag here is what I have in my form and this does not seem to work. <input name="txtNumber" ng-disabled="somevalue" min="1" step="1" type="number" ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="someNumber" class="form-control color-black" />

Comment: @imkost I am using chrome, but need to support IE9, firefox.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the `min` attribute, although check for [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number);

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="1">
```

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="number" step="1" min="0">`

`type` is the type of the input field, `step` defines the stepping of allowed numbers, i. e. only whole numbers are allowed, and finally setting `min` to zero means that negative numbers aren't allowed. Thusly only positive whole numbers (integers) and zero is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Right Guys,

Thanks for posting some valid answers however my requirement was something else. Hence I decided to write my own directive to fix this issue.

```
'use strict';
```

(function () {
    var app = angular.module("common");

```
var onlyInteger = function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
                var transformedValue = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');                    
                if (transformedValue !== inputValue) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(transformedValue);
                    ctrl.$render();
                }

                return transformedValue;
            });
        }
    };
};

app.directive('onlyInteger', onlyInteger);
}());

<div class="row bottom-spaced-small">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Number
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input name="txtNumber" only-integer ng-required="true" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="someNumber" class="form-control color-black" />
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-left: 30px" ng-if="someForm.$submitted && !someForm.txtNumber.$valid">
            <span style="color: red">Number is mandatory and must be a non 0 positive number.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Two things here, I have removed the control as number type="number" and included the directive as attribute.

The pattern written in the control is pretty much bound and static. If we wish to be a bit more generic, then pass the pattern as an attribute and capture inside the directive to validate against that pattern.

Open to Suggestions and corrections.

Answer (score 0):

User

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48" min="1" >
```